# Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Use set builder notation and logical equivalences to show that $\;A\cup(B\setminus A) = A\cup B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Use set builder notation and logical equivalences to show that $\;A\cup(B\setminus A) = A\cup B$.

**My attempt**:

I started with $$\;A\cup(B\setminus A) = \big\{x : x\in A\lor x\in B\setminus A\big\}$$ but then I got struggled.

Could you help me to complete the proof?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Fun fact: any proof of the kind you request, including @LionHeart's, is isomorphic to a proof of the tautology $A\lor(B\land\neg A)=A\lor B$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A^\prime$ be the complement of $A$ that is the set of the elements which are not in $A$.

$\;A\cup(B\setminus A) =\big\{x : x\in A\lor(x\in B \land x\in A')\big\}\\=\big\{x : (x\in A\lor x\in B)\land (x \in A \lor x\in A')\big\}\\=\big\{x : (x\in A\lor x\in B) \land (x \in U)\big\}\\=\;(A\cup B)\cap U=A\cup B.$

Comment: Awesome! What does the ' denote?

Comment: A' means complement of A

Comment: @Finjamen ; $A'=A^c=U - A$

Comment: $A^\prime$ denotes $U\setminus A$ that is the set of the elements which are not in $A$. Its name is complement of $A$.

Comment: @Angelo: Thanks